# Query/Script to delete an order in SAP Hybris (backend)

Tags: sql, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

To free-up storage in the database and increase the performance, we need to delete the previously placed orders in SAP Hybris Commerce. The orders should be deleted for a particular time frame such that only the orders older than X days should be deleted.

Can anyone help me with impex/script for deleting the previously placed orders?
Impex for selecting all orders :

> SELECT * from {orders}

Answer (score 0):

These operations will create huge system load.

Hybris has own functionality for these: [Data Retention Framework](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2268d55f40c94c5e8c43fa47f3b609a4.html?locale=en-US&q=data%20retention%20framework)

You will also need to add your own select queries. You wrote that older than X days. When this X days counter start: order creation/update, delivery, return, payment, etc?

Comment: Can you please look into this?

      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74688357/how-to-use-lambda-expression-in-groovy-script