# How to use lambda expression in groovy script?

Tags: java, groovy, lambda

I am trying to write a groovy script code, but found out that groovy script does not support lambda expressions.
**Can someone help me convert this piece of code so that it works for groovy script as well?**

```
        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(orderModel.getFreeProductSets())){
        orderModel.getFreeProductSets().forEach(orderFreeProductSetModel -> {
            if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(orderFreeProductSetModel.getFreeProducts())){
                modelService.removeAll(orderFreeProductSetModel.getFreeProducts());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("no entry found for orderFreeProductSetModel");
            }
        });
        modelService.removeAll(orderModel.getFreeProductSets());
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("FreeProductSets is empty");
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(orderModel.getFreeProductSets())) {
    orderModel.getFreeProductSets().each{ orderFreeProductSetModel ->
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(orderFreeProductSetModel.getFreeProducts())) {
            modelService.removeAll(orderFreeProductSetModel.getFreeProducts());
        } else {
            System.out.println("no entry found for orderFreeProductSetModel");
        }
    };
    modelService.removeAll(orderModel.getFreeProductSets());
} else {
    System.out.println("FreeProductSets is empty");
}
```

You just needed to use foreach{} instead of foreach()

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It's just the syntax of groovy, you need to use foreach{ it-> ..} or each {it->..}, instead of foreach( it-> .)  in java syntax

Comment: STILL FAILING: THE EXCEPTION IS:  Script compilation has failed [reason: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script78.groovy: 20: Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block;

   solution: Add an explicit closure parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...} @ line 20, column 75.

   { orderFreeProductSetModel -> {

                                 ^

1 error
]

Comment: I have updated the script, please try again now

Comment: Thank you so much :) Working fine now. 
Can you please tell me what was the error I made?

Comment: You needed to use `orderModel.getFreeProductSets().forEach{ orderFreeProductSetModel -> ..}` instead of `orderModel.getFreeProductSets().forEach(orderFreeProductSetModel -> {})`, you just had an error in the syntax